# $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sin(\pi\sqrt{n^2+1})$

Tags: limits, analysis

I have a question regarding my method of finding a limit for my analysis class.

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sin(\pi\sqrt{n^2+1})$.

The method I used was I noticed that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(n^2+1)$ I think, so then that means $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sin(\pi\sqrt{n^2+1}) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sin(n\pi)$ then for all $n \in \Bbb N, \sin(n\pi) = 0$, thus $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sin(\pi\sqrt{n^2+1}) = 0$. Is this a good way to do this?

If not, why, and what would be a good way to do this problem.

Also, what is a good way to show $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}n = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}(n^2+1)$. I reached the conclusion using intuition (and a C++ script), but I don't think thats rigorous enough.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The result is correct, the derivation is not. For example, it is also true that $\lim n =\lim e^n$ since both are infinity just like $\lim (n^2 +1)$. Are you familiar with Taylor series?

Comment: No, there is no justification for equality between limits. One method is to factorize by $n\pi$ Inside sinus. $\sin\left(n\pi\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}\right)=\sin\left( n\pi\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}-1\right)+n\pi\right)$

Comment: Yes. I am familiar with Taylor series, and I think I see where you're going with that, but we have not discussed them in class, so I do not know if my professor would want us to use them.

Answer (score 5):

Using $\sqrt{n^2+1}=n+\dfrac{1}{n+\sqrt{n^2+1}}$, we can deduce that:

$$\sin (\pi \sqrt{n^2+1})=(-1)^n\sin \left(\frac{\pi}{n+\sqrt{n^2+1}}\right)$$

$(-1)^n$ is bounded and:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{n+\sqrt{n^2+1}}\right) = 0$$

so the final results is $0$.

Comment: How did you reach that original equality? I'm not doubting the validity, it just seems kind of random to me.

Comment: @TylerSmith It's a known rationalization formula $\sqrt{a}-\sqrt{b}=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}$ for $a=n^2+1$ and $b=n^2$. The idea comes from trying to determine exactly  $\sqrt{n^2+1}$ as $n+$ 'something very small', instead of approximating $\sqrt{n^2+1} \approx n$ for large $n$.

Comment: @TylerSmith It's effectively the Difference of Squares with $a^2, b^2 \mapsto a, b$.

Answer (score 2):

One elementary way to do this is to "extract" the equivalent $n\pi$ like this :
$$\pi\sqrt{n^2+1}=n\pi\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}$$
and observe the behaviour of the square root :
$$\epsilon_n = \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}-1 = \frac{(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}-1)(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}+1)}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}+1} = \frac{\frac{1}{n^2}}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n^2}}+1}\le \frac{1}{2n^2}$$
so
$$\sin(\pi\sqrt{1+n^2}) = \sin(n\pi+n\epsilon_n) = (-1)^n\sin(n\epsilon_n)$$
and as $n\epsilon_n\xrightarrow[]{n\to\infty}0$, you can conclude.

Note that this can also be used to prove that the series $\sum\sin(\pi\sqrt{n^2+1})$ converges.

Answer (score 1):

$$L=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sin (\pi\sqrt{n^2+1})=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sin (n\pi (1+\frac{1}{n^2})^{1/2})$$
$$L=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sin (n\pi(1+\frac{1}{2n^2})=\sin n\pi=0$$

Answer (score 1):

$|\sin (π(n^2+1)^{1/2}-nπ)+nπ)|=$

$|\sin(π(n^2+1)^{1/2})\cos nπ+$

$ \cos (π(n^2+1)^{1/2}-nπ)\sin nπ)|=$

$|\sin (π(n^2+1)^{1/2}-nπ)\ cos (nπ)|=$

$|\sin (π(n^2+1)^{1/2}-nπ)||\cos (nπ)|$

$=|\sin (π(n^2+1)^{1/2}-nπ)|\cdot 1.$

$f(n)=π(n^2+1)^{1/2}-nπ=$

$π\dfrac{1}{(n^2+1)^{1/2}+n};$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(n)=0$;

Finally

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty }|\sin (f(n))|=$

$|\sin (\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(n))|= |\sin (0)|=0$.